# How to open file in Emacs via eshell?

Tags: emacs, buffer, eshell

When in eshell is there a command for opening a file in another buffer?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can call elisp functions directly.  So to open a file, call `find-file` on the filename.  Example:

```
~ $ ls
myfile
~ $ (find-file "myfile")
```

Parentheses and quotes are optional, so this works too:

```
~ $ find-file myfile
```

Comment: I don't think this really answers the "meant" question, but it answers the asked question. What I mean is that people finding this question are probably looking for a command line command to type in eshell, maybe because they do not want to use `C-x C-f`, for whatever reason.

Comment: I usually have emacs split into two windows, and want to open the file in the other window, instead of replacing my eshell session: `find-file-other-window myfile`

Answer (score 17):

In eshell, you don't have to use the entire path when using the find file command.  Hitting C-x C-f is the same as typing find-file, and eshell sets the directory to the one you are currently browsing.  This is the advantage to me over using ansi-term. Try it out.

Answer (score 7):

find-file basically does it, as ataylor and ryan kung indicated earlier.

```
$ find-file myfile
```

but, using eshell itself, you can also can set an even shorter alias:

```
$ alias ff 'for i in ${eshell-flatten-list $*} {find-file $i}'
```

(and eshell remembers it permanently). so from now you can just type:

```
$ ff myfile
```

thanks to [this tutorial](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EshellAlias)

Comment: Another way to make the ff alias:
`alias ff 'find-file $1'`

Answer (score 2):

The elisp funct can be directly used in eshell, so you can try:

```
find-file <filename>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use eshell? 'C-x f' and type the location of your file.

Comment: Well it's just the thing that I don't want to type an entire path since I'm already at some location in shell. Still I guess that at some point of my emacs adventure I'm going to use dired. In a ['commander way'](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Sunrise_Commander)

Comment: I think if you try it you will discover that 'C-x C-f' actually opens in the directory you're browsing. Plus you'll get ido completion!